# facing issues while creating dll file for CAPL using Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, dll, capl, canoe

I am trying to implement AES-CMAC (128 bit)calculation in CAPL. I created a C++ code(visual studio code 2019) using CryptoPP. it is working properly indendenlty. When I try to create a dll file for the implementation and include it in CAPL, the function is not seen in CAPL browser.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I built this code and included the dll file in CAPL

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Does anyone know where I went wrong?

EDIT: For now I am hardcoding Key and plain text in GenerateMAC(). I will be using the values passed in function once the code works.

Comment: Don't post images of code.

Comment: You most likely have to escape the back-slashes in the path to the library.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the screenshots are no longer available.

But here are some points to check:

- Are the functions exported in the "CAPL-own" export table (CAPL_DLL_INFO) correctly?
- Is the CDLL compiled for the correct architecture? CDLLs are loaded and run within RuntimeKernel.exe - and this is (at least until CanOE 12) a 32-bit executable.

It is also advisable to extend the sample configurations for CDLLs (C:\Users\Public\Sample Configurations x.y.z\Programming\CAPLdll) according to your own needs.